# How to get ajax response on a button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting table data from ajax response as json.
Some json datas am not displaying but I want it on a button click for other purpose.How can I get it?Please help me.

```
 function leaveTable() {
     for (var i = 0; i < leaveList.length; i++) {
         var tab = '<tr id="' + i + '"><td>' + (i + 1) + '</td><td class="appliedOn">' + leaveList[i].appliedOn + '</td><td class="levType" >' + leaveList[i].levType + '</td><td class="leaveOn" >' + leaveList[i].leaveOn + '</td><td class="duration">' + leaveList[i].duration + '</td><td class="status">' + leaveList[i].status + '</td><td class="approvedOn">' + leaveList[i].approvedOn + '</td><td class="approvedBy">' + leaveList[i].approvedBy + '</td><td><i class="btn dltLev fa fa-times" onclick="cancelLeave(this)" data-dismiss="modal"  value="Cancelled"></i></td><tr>';

         $('#levListTable').append(tab)
     }
 }
```

from ajax response I want `leaveTypeId` and pass it into `sendCancelReq()` function.
Complete code :https://jsfiddle.net/tytzuckz/18/

Answer (score 1):

It is complicated to know exactly what you want. I hope that helps you:

The first, I would change, is *not* to produce the JavaScript events in your html code `var tab = ...`. I think, it is more clear and readable, when you add your event after the creation of the new dom elements. For example:

```
var tab = $('<tr id="' + i + '">' + 
  '<td>' + (i + 1) + '</td>' + 
  '<td class="appliedOn">' + leaveList[i].appliedOn + '</td>' + 
  '<td class="levType" >' + leaveList[i].levType + '</td>' + 
  '<td class="leaveOn" >' + leaveList[i].leaveOn + '</td>' + 
  '<td class="duration">' + leaveList[i].duration + '</td>' + 
  '<td class="status">' + leaveList[i].status + '</td>' + 
  '<td class="approvedOn">' + leaveList[i].approvedOn + '</td>' + 
  '<td class="approvedBy">' + leaveList[i].approvedBy + '</td>' + 
  '<td><i class="btn dltLev fa fa-times" data-dismiss="modal"  value="Cancelled"></i></td>' + 
  '<tr>');
$(tab).find('.btn.dltLev').click(function () { cancelLeave(this); });
```

Then, you are able to send your necessary information more clearly, e.g.:

Instead of the last code

```
$(tab).find('.btn.dltLev').click(function () { cancelLeave(this); });
```

you can write

```
$(tab).find('.btn.dltLev').click(function () { cancelLeave(this, leaveList[i].leaveTypeId); });
```

and extend your method `cancelLeave` to:

```
function cancelLeave(elem, leaveTypeId) {
  var id = $(elem).closest('tr').attr('id')
  alert(id)
  $("#cancelLeave").modal("show");
  $('.sendCancelReq').val(id);
  sendCancelReq(leaveTypeId);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Got solution
Please check this:https://jsfiddle.net/tytzuckz/19/

```
 function cancelLeave(elem) {
    var levTypeId = $(elem).attr('id')
    var id = $(elem).closest('tr').attr('id')
    $('.currentLevTypeId').val(levTypeId);
     $("#cancelLeave").modal("show");
     $('.sendCancelReq').val(id);

   }
   function sendCancelReq() {

  var a= $('.currentLevTypeId').val();
   alert(a)
 }
```